# fancybox 3.2.5 и зацикливание галереи

Tags: jquery, fancybox

В старом фансибоксе достаточно было прописать

> cyclic: true

В новом так не получается ...

Как зациклить галерею в свежей версии?

Answer (score 0):

все оказалось очень просто)

> loop: true